# A named route was found for but matching failed

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.x

I have a strange problem with cakephp 3 and named routes.

```
  foreach ($categoryProducts as $key => $categoryProduct) {

    /**
     * WORK
     * Result : http://www.website.com/shop/slugshop/products/slugcategory
     */
    $categoryProduct->href_shop_view = Router::url([
      'slug' => $shop->slug,
      'category' => 'some_caractere'.$categoryProduct->slug,
       '_name' => 'viewShopProductsByCategory'
     ]);

    /**
     * Dont't work
     * Result : A named route was found for "viewShopProductsByCategory", but matching failed. 
     */
    $categoryProduct->href_shop_view = Router::url([
      'slug' => $shop->slug,
      'category' => $categoryProduct->slug,
      '_name' => 'viewShopProductsByCategory'
    ]);

  }
```

And in my routes.php

```
Router::connect('/shop/:slug/products/:category',
     ['controller' => 'shops','action' => 'products'],
     ['slug'=>'[^\/]+','category'=>'[^\/]+','pass'=>['slug','category'],'_name' => 'viewShopProductsByCategory'
   ]
);
```

Can you help me please, because i don't found the solution yet and i don't understand my mistake...

Thank you for your help

**Edit 1**

@ndm Like you can see i use the same named route, with same shop slug and category slug.

But it's like if **$categoryProduct->slug** return nothing if you don't put somme caractere before

**Edit 2**

```
debug($categoryProduct->slug); // Return "e-cigarette"
debug($shopp->slug); // Return "vapoton-com"
```

If i write directly :

```
$categoryProduct->href_shop_view = Router::url([
  'slug' => 'vapoton-com',
  'category' => 'e-cigarette',
   '_name' => 'viewShopProductsByCategory'
 ]);
```

It's work !

Thanks for your help

Comment: That means that the values for `slug` and/or `category` didn't match your routes rules. Start with checking what exactly they contain and update your question with that information.

Comment: Again, please update your question with the _exact_ values of the properties, assuming things isn't helpful in the world of programming. Check `debug($shop->slug);` and `debug($categoryProduct->slug)` to figure what exactly you are working with when things go wrong.

Comment: If that is really what the properties contain (and they do not mutate on read), and that is really your exact code, then I'd kinda doubt that this error would occur. As it stands, your problem unfortunately isn't reproducable, so I don't think that you'll get any answers here, other than suggestions to debug things further. Try to hook into the code that triggers the exception and check the values in there again.